# Single custom template file for multiple URLs, in Drupal 7

Tags: theming

How do I use same custom template file for multiple URLs in Drupal 7?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the problem you're trying to solve? It's also helpful to tag your question with the Drupal version since the answer might be different depending on the version.

Comment: To which template file are you referring?